# How to diagnose the cause for failed rendering

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I am writing a Reagent application using Figwheel. What I am struggling with is to figure out why rendering of a given component fails. What would you recommend as the best way to diagnose these kinds of problems?

Here is what I see in the JavaScript console in the browser:

```
Error rendering component (in brain.comps.worklog)
reagent$impl$component$do_render — component.cljs:126
(anonymous function) — component.cljs:143
reagent$ratom$in_context — ratom.cljs:37
reagent$ratom$deref_capture — ratom.cljs:43 reagent$ratom$run_in_reaction — ratom.cljs:504
brain.comps.worklog_render — component.cljs:143
finishClassComponent — react-dom.inc.js:8835
performUnitOfWork — react-dom.inc.js:12260
workLoop — react-dom.inc.js:12289
renderRoot — react-dom.inc.js:12320
performWorkOnRoot — react-dom.inc.js:12895
performWork — react-dom.inc.js:12816
performSyncWork — react-dom.inc.js:12793
requestWork — react-dom.inc.js:12693
scheduleWorkImpl — react-dom.inc.js:12568
scheduleRootUpdate — react-dom.inc.js:13156
(anonymous function) — react-dom.inc.js:16647
(anonymous function) — react-dom.inc.js:17066
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer — react-dom.inc.js:17062
reagent$dom$render_comp — dom.cljs:20
(anonymous function) — dom.cljs:44
reagent$dom$render — dom.cljs:31
(anonymous function) — dom.cljs:39
reagent$dom$render — dom.cljs:31
Global Code — main.cljs:21
reagent$impl$component$do_render — component.cljs:126
```

Comment: Please update your question and provide the output from the terminal or the JavaScript console (in Developer tools) if it's not showing up in the browser itself.

Comment: I hope the stack trace helps to understand where I am stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately It's hard to tell from the stacktrace alone. Can you provide a minimal code example that causes the error above?

Comment: It's actually more about the general way to do this then this specific error. Are there any how tos out there? It should be fairly straightforward as my "stuff" is getting compiled into a VDOM for react first, and it should be possible to run that process independent of the browser.